# Extract text from PDF use iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use this code for read pdf content. But it not working with some pdf file.

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog _of = new OpenFileDialog();
    StringBuilder _text = new StringBuilder();

    if (_of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string _PdfOPath = _of.FileName.ToString();

        if (File.Exists(_PdfOPath))
        {
            PdfReader _pdfReader = new PdfReader(_PdfOPath);
            for (int page = 1; page <= _pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(_pdfReader, page, strategy);
                _text.Append(currentText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another case I change

> SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()

to

> LocationTextExtractionStrategy()

But always receive "\n\n".
What is the solution ?

This is my PDF file.[PDF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rr_0TA3Bb_ZUhiMFViZDlweUU/view?usp=sharing)

Update
I tried many website convert PDF online and I found this.
https://www.pdftoexcel.com/

It's so amazing service and free. I'm really want to know how they can do that.

Comment: Have you tried encoding `currentText` before appending it? `currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));`

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but nothing change. I always get value "\n\n\n\n\n\n"
P/S: My pdf file have english and japanese too, but i think no problems.
I have another japanese pdf and its work fine.

Comment: If it works with only english and only japanese, and not with both?

Comment: It works with both of languages. I have check with another pdf file and it works fine.

Comment: If it works with one file and not with another, then you need to share your file.

Comment: Some PDFs simply do not contain the information required for text extraction. Most likely the PDFs for which your code does not work as desired are such cases.

Comment: I didn't recognize the cause immediately; I'll look into it later this week.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45801151/1729265). While there the font encoding was **Identity-H** in combination with a ROS Adobe-CNS1-4, it in your case is **UniJIS-UCS2-H** with Adobe-Japan1-0. In both cases the tables representing the Asian encodings are not contained in the standard iTextSharp distribution but in extra files, iTextAsian.dll and iTextAsianCmaps.dll, which you have to add to your project and add to iText's resource search path like this

```
StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian"));
StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsianCmaps"));
```

You can retrieve the DLLs e.g. [here on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/extras/).

Applied to your sample file, this test

```
StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian"));
StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsianCmaps"));
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"selection.pdf");
var pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
Console.Out.Write("Content: {0}", pageText);
```

outputs

```
Content: 東芝 現品票 東芝 現品票
2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所 2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所
 注文番号 受注納期 注文番号 受注納期
53M77062-01 2017/03/14 540117RJ-01 2017/03/14
 図番 図番
4X14-22886 WX58-47630*B   1
 品名 数量 品名 数量
SPACER           G0A
1
LINK
2
東芝 現品票 東芝 現品票
2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所 2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所
 注文番号 受注納期 注文番号 受注納期
540333RJ-01 2017/03/15 540523RF-01 2017/03/13
 図番 図番
2X79-36722 WX79-05236     1
 品名 数量 品名 数量
COVER
1
PLATEMTG
3
東芝 現品票 東芝 現品票
2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所 2017/03/09 便 ㈱玉吉製作所
 注文番号 受注納期 注文番号 受注納期
540681RJ-01 2017/03/15 54A87736-01 2017/03/14
 図番 図番
3X17-46654*B 3X12-38439*A
 品名 数量 品名 数量
PLATEMTG
3
PLATE            G00
10
```