# iTextSharp library does not extract text from my file

Tags: c#, itext

iTextSharp library (version 5.5.5) does not extract text from my file.
I can copy and paste text from pdf into Notepad.
I uploaded file to [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4ws2fhr72xaa3s/Text%20Extraction%20-%20Colddishes_C.pdf?dl=0) link.

The source code is very simple and it works for other pdf files, but for this problematic file all I get is some characters without any meaning.

```
var text = string.Empty;
using (var file = new File.OpenRead(path))
{
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))
    {
        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
        {
            text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question and added c# code.

Comment: @NenadVlajic Did my answer help or are there still issues? If it helped, please accept it (click the tick at its upper left). If there are still missing or misinterpreted text pieces, please illustrate by pointing out an example.

Comment: @mkl I googled for iTextAsian.dll and iTextAsianCmaps.dll and added them to my project. I had to find a way how to tell iTextSharp that they exist, and the way I did it is to add static constructor to my text extraction class. I will post separate answer to include this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF declarations of the Asian fonts in your sample PDF do not contain a **ToUnicode** map to allow mapping from character codes to Unicode.

Furthermore, their encoding is **Identity-H** which is kind of a pseudo-encoding as it merely maps 2-byte character codes ranging from 0 to 65,535 to the same 2-byte CID value, so this still doesn't define a fixed encoding usable for text extraction.

**Identity-H** may actually only be used with CIDFonts using any **Registry**, **Ordering**, and **Supplement** values, and these *ROS* values convey the actual encoding information from which a mapping to Unicode can be derived. This is the case in your file.

To make use of these *ROS* values during text extraction, iText needs a set of resource files defining the mappings for the different predefined *ROS* values. As these files are quite huge, they are not part of the standard iText main distribution jar/dll but have to be added to the class path as a separate jar/dll file.

*I only tested this using the Java version of iText as I am more proficient with it.*

#### iText 5.x/Java

The Maven coordinates for the 5.x version of this jar artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-asian</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(As nothing has changed in these resources in the course of the recent years, there have been no 5.x releases since 5.2.0.)

After I added that jar to the classpath here, I could successfully extract Asian characters from your PDF. Whether they are 100% correct, I cannot say as I cannot read them.

#### iTextSharp 5.x/.Net

There should be a similar iTextSharp DLL with Asian font resources. (I found the iText 7 variant thereof but I am not sure that that works with a 5.x iTextSharp.)

Googl'ing around one finds a number of `iTextAsian-*`, `iTextAsianCmaps-*`, and `iTextAsian-all-*` files... I don't know, though, which of them work with the current iTextSharp 5.5.12.

As the OP found out, one additionally has to register the DLLs for iTextSharp (in contrast to iText / Java):

> Here is how to notify iTextSharp that Asian dlls are in the project. You need to add static constructor of yours text extraction class:
>
> ```
> static PdfDocument()
> {
>     iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsian.dll");    
>     iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsianCmaps.dll");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have addition to the answer given by @mkl. Here is how to notify iTextSharp that Asian dlls are in the project. You need to add static constructor of yours text extraction class:

```
static PdfDocument()
{
    iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsian.dll");    
    iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch("iTextAsianCmaps.dll");
}
```

Comment: @mkl If you can edit your answer to include this step I will marked it as accepted. Thanks for the help! It is really simple solution!

Comment: *"If you can edit your answer to include this step"* - OK, I've added that step to my answer.