# Extract PDF content failed using iTextSharp because of special fonts

Tags: c#, itext, extract, cjk

I can extract content from most PDF files with the following code.

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Path);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy); 
        }
```

[image: Failed extraction file Property]

I'm trying to find solutions online.I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662544/itextsharp-library-does-not-extract-text-from-my-file) might be useful to me.

```
 StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian")
        );
        StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsianCmaps")
        );
```

[image: Result]
But it still doesn't work.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

I uploaded the [pdf](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1VRsg_dVwi74l3_Xsjyiq9Q) file.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question. And please be aware that there even are some PDFs from which text extraction is not possible because important information are missing. In that case you'll have to try ocr.

Comment: @mkl I upload the failed to extract the file, thanks for your reply

Comment: Ehm, which is the download button?

Comment: The second button, to the right of the blue one. Google Chrome automagically offered to translate the page.

Comment: @mkl  https://pan.baidu.com/s/1VRsg_dVwi74l3_Xsjyiq9Q

Comment: @Amedee unfortunately the mobile chrome version here did not. ;)

Comment: Without loading those extra resources I get an empty string result, too, but having loaded them I get the page text, at first glance it is complete. Just to be sure, you have added the iTextAsian.dll and iTextAsianCmaps.dll to your project references?

Comment: @mkl I have added the iTextAsian.dll and iTextAsianCmaps.dll to my project references,but I still get an empty return.Can you share the success code?

Comment: The successful code is that from your screen shot. Just to be sure, which iText version do you use?

Comment: @mkl The latest 5.5.13，or share your console programs solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested extracting text from your document using this NUnit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void ExtractText易城数据运营商报告()
{
    StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian"));
    StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsianCmaps"));
    Console.Out.Write("Text Extraction - 易城数据运营商报告.pdf\n\n");
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"d:\Issues\stackoverflow\Extract PDF content failed using iTextSharp because of special fonts\易城数据运营商报告.pdf");
    var pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
    Console.Out.Write("Content: {0}", pageText);
}
```

Both the iTextAsian.dll and the iTextAsianCmaps.dll have been added to the project references.

The output:

```
Testname:   ExtractText易城数据运营商报告
Testergebnis:   Erfolgreiche
Ergebnis StandardOutput:    
Text Extraction - 易城数据运营商报告.pdf

Content: 【易城数据】运营商报告 
1. 星级评估
2. 申请人基本信息
3. 运营商基本信息
4. 风险信息扫描
5. 通信记录相关

20180304221448070909 2018-03-04 22:14:48
风险等级评估:低 信用量划分:608
身份特征星级:★★★☆☆ 消费能力星级:★★☆☆☆
通信行为星级:★☆☆☆☆ 人脉关系星级:★★★☆☆
姓名:李延峰 性别:男
年龄:29 手机号:15063976462
身份证:370211198908240056
未能获取运营商注册的身份证
与运营商注册的姓名【**峰】明文匹配
手机号: 15063976462 运营商类型： 中国移动
姓名： **峰 身份证号：
邮箱： 地址：
会员等级： 2 积分值： 0分
在网时长： 21月 套餐类型：
可用余额： 44.16 手机归属地： 山东青岛
主要活动区域： 本地活动时间占比：100%
运营商关键信息匹配 未能获取运营商注册的身份证
与运营商注册的姓名【**峰】明文匹配
风险：低
入网时长检查 入网时长大于6个月 风险：低
申请人黑名单命中检查 手机号未在黑名单中出现
身份证未在黑名单中出现
风险：低
紧急联系人黑名单命中检查 未知
黑名单通信记录 共与null个号码通信 风险：低
紧急联系人通信记录 无输入信息 未知
民间借贷通信记录 未发现 风险：低
金融机构通信记录
【招商银行】
被叫0次共0分钟 主叫1次共6分钟
【近24小时】
未发现
【1-7天】
未发现
【7-30天】
未发现
【30-90天】
1个号码 联系1次 共6分钟
【90-180天】
未发现
风险：低
信用卡机构通信记录
【招商银行】
被叫0次共0分钟 主叫2次共7分钟
【近24小时】
未发现
【1-7天】
未发现
【7-30天】
未发现
【30-90天】
1个号码 联系2次 共7分钟
【90-180天】
未发现
风险：低
P2P平台与互联网小贷通信记录 未发现 风险：低
P2P平台与互联网小贷联系记录 未发现 风险：低
```

I use iText for .Net (aka iTextSharp) version 5.5.13.0, iTextAsian.dll 2.1.0.0, and iTextAsianCmaps.dll 1.0.0.0. The test runs in Visual Studio Community 2017 with current NUnit references.

Comment: Thank you very much.I succeeded in getting the text according to your instructions.I failed because I referenced the wrong DLL version.( iTextAsian.dll 1.0, iTextAsianCmaps.dll 1.0.)